# как сделать простой field и dropdownlist(или Select2) в одном в yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, select2

Помогите как сделать простой field и dropdownlist(или Select2) в одном в yii2.
То есть если есть фамилия в списке выбираешь если нету в списке заполняешь поле. Но данные из списка берутся из справочника (из другой таблицы) и добавляется на это! как осуществит это? на интернете не нашел ничего

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить инпут и селект в форму. При выборе значения из списка, подставлять его в инпут. Два существенных минуса:

1. Денормализация данных в БД (со своими вытекающими).
2. Усложнится поиск, фильтрация и сортировка по этому полю.

Если данные в списке формируются из другой таблицы, то в первую обычно пишут айдишник для связи. Чтобы получить айдишник, сначала надо добавить сущность в таблицу. Можно добавить поле для второй таблицы и в контроллере проверять его на наличие данных. Если есть, то добавить запись, а айдишник (или чем надо связать) в первую таблицу.